# How to hide deleted entities

Tags: entity-framework

I'm currently working with EntityFramework and I came across a big problem. When I Remove an entity from a DbSet, it's not removed at all. This is quite annoying when filtering the DbSet, because before deleted entities suddenly appear again.
How can I "hide" deleted entities?

Comment: `DbSet` should remove deleted entities upon calling `DbContext.SaveChanges`. If you can't do that, you can use `DbSet.Local` instead represents your in-memory entities which won't include deleted entities.

Comment: ah, it works! Thank you!

Comment: Since the DbSet offers more functions for querying, I guess that one should work with it instead of the .Local Property.